# What are some Soviet and Allied counters for Yuri's mastermind tanks?

Tags: command-and-conquer-red-alert-2, command-and-conquer-yuris-revenge

Just finished playing the Allied campaign, and the mastermind tanks are a massive pain. I tried to blow them up from a distance with prism tanks, but their armor is very heavy.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, mind control doesn't work on flying units, such as choppers or Kirov airships. I haven't played this in ages, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [here](http://cnc.wikia.com/wiki/Mastermind_%28Red_Alert%29):

> One major weakness with this weapon system however, is its lack of
>   self-defensive armament. This makes it completely helpless against
>   units immune to psychic control such as Terror drones, robot tanks and
>   air units when airborne. As mentioned above however, it's greatest
>   weakness is that this weapons system is prone to burning out when it
>   has too many units under its control. This led to the tactic of
>   rushing the Mastermind with many cheap and fast units such as
>   Conscripts, Flak Tracks or IFVs. Paratrooper conscripts are ideal for
>   this task as they are both free and plentiful. Yuri's Masterminds can
>   control up to 3 units each without going into overdrive.

**Summary**:

1. Rush with cheap units to achieve self destruct.
2. Use flyers or robots (terror drone, robot tank) as immune to control

Comment: 3. Sneak a couple of prism tanks to just out of control range of  his base and park 'em there, let 'em sneak-snipe every unit that comes out. :)